Finding existing subtotals in a pandas dataframe or a list of numbers
Here's an interesting problem. Given a pandas Dataframe (or even a Python list) how would one go about finding the subtotals that might be in that list? For example:
    running  value
0     False  50709
1     False  26715
2     False   1715
3     False  79139
4     False  34447
5     False  -7256
6     False   1210
7     False  42913
8      True  36227
9     False    999
10    False  20107
11    False   5787
12    False  -1466
13    False   -216
14    False    615
15    False  24827
16     True  11400
17    False   5642
18     True   5758
19    False     -5
20     True   5753

Observations about the data:

Signs may be incorrect.
There are both subtotals and running totals in the data. Lines [3, 7, 15] are subtotals, [8, 16, 18, 20] are running totals.
Subtotal 3 could be considered a special case, as it's both a subtotal and a running total.
I can determine the running totals through other means, therefore they are marked True in the sample data.
Subtotals [3, 7, 15] represent rows [0, 1, 2], [4, 5, 6] and [10, 11, 12, 13, 14] respectively.
It's fair to assume a subtotal follows a contiguous subset of numbers.
There might not be any subtotals.
I don't know if there are cases where a subtotal set includes another smaller subtotal set. Even an answer that doesn't consider this will be helpful.
The number of rows will relatively small, less than 100.

I need to identify subtotals and the rows represented by each subtotal.
See my answer below.

This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?  for more details.

@itpror66 From your "please see" I take "a primary characteristic of a good question is that it is likely to be searched by someone else". Well, it may not be true in whatever is your area of specialty but finding a subtotal from a list of unreliably signed numbers happens to be an interesting problem in the accounting world. It's a simplified form of the subset-sum problem which you may be aware is an interesting problem too.

I have an answer:
import pandas as pd


def gen_subtotal_indices(df):
    targets = {0,}  #used for fast test of inclusion since targets_lst gets big fast
    targets_lst = [0]
    signs = [[]]
    indices = []
    for i, r in df.iterrows():
        if r['running']:
            continue
        v = r['value']
        if v in targets:
            yield i, indices, signs[targets_lst.index(v)]
            targets = {0,}
            targets_lst = [0]
            signs = [[]]
            indices = []
            continue
        targets |= {t + x for t in targets for x in (0, v, -v)}
        targets_lst = [t + x for t in targets_lst for x in (0, v, -v)]
        signs = [t + [x] for t in signs for x in (0, 1, -1)]
        indices.append(i)


df = pd.DataFrame({'running': [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False,
                               False, False, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, True],
                   'value': [50709, 26715, 1715, 79139, 34447, -7256, 1210, 42913, 36227, 999, 20107, 5787, -1466,
                             -216, 615, 24827, 11400, 5642, 5758, -5, 5753]})

print(df)
for subtotal_ix, detail_ix, signs in gen_subtotal_indices(df):
    print(subtotal_ix, detail_ix, signs)

produces
3 [0, 1, 2] [1, 1, 1]
7 [4, 5, 6] [1, -1, 1]
15 [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14] [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Which you can see has the index of the subtotal followed by the indices of the included items, followed by a vector containing 0, 1 or -1 indicating the multiplier on the original data. Could probably be better but this is the general idea.
Any thoughts or improvements appreciated!
